# Steroids/PhoneGap CSS Won't Load

Tags: css, cordova, steroids

I'm trying to use Steroids with AngularJS for an application. Below is the stuff in my `head` tag.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/vendor/ionic/css/ionic.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/application.css" />

<script src="http://localhost/cordova.js"></script>
<script src="/components/steroids-js/steroids.js"></script>

<script src="/components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="/components/angular-touch/angular-touch.min.js"></script>

<script src="/components/lodash/dist/lodash.min.js"></script>

<script src="/components/restangular/dist/restangular.min.js"></script>
<script src="/models/<%= yield.controller %>.js"></script>

<script src="/controllers/<%= yield.controller %>.js"></script>
```

Now, I can tell the scripts are working, because the Angular stuff is. But the CSS won't load at all. It's in the `/dist` folder under the correct location, but it just won't load. Copy and pasting into a `<style>` works.

Any idea how I can fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Hard to debug if we don't have an environment to look at.

Comment: What information do you need?

Comment: Can you provide a link to a repo with code?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the DOCTYPE tag on your layout html file. It is a known issue, hope they fix this problem soon.